How to open a bottom sheet with modal 3D stack animation on iOS?
I try to achieve something like below:

to open my news editor in a separated window that overlaps the previous one (unfortunately, I don't know a right name for that mechanics in iOS).
Now, I am using modal-bottom-sheet and go-router packages to achieve such effect. However, it's just failed with errors:
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
#0      CupertinoScaffold.showCupertinoModalBottomSheet (package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheets/cupertino_bottom_sheet.dart:456:52)
#1      _NewsfeedPageState._onCupertinoAddPressed (package:myapp/presentation/newsfeed.dart:131:23)
#2      _NewsfeedPageState._buildAppBar.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package: myapp/presentation/newsfeed.dart:78:30)
#3      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:351:24)
#4      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:656:11)
#5      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:313:5)
#6      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:246:7)
#7      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:703:9)
#8      PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/<…>
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
#0      CupertinoScaffold.showCupertinoModalBottomSheet (package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheets/cupertino_bottom_sheet.dart:456:52)
#1      _NewsfeedPageState._onCupertinoAddPressed (package: myapp/presentation/newsfeed.dart:131:23)
#2      _NewsfeedPageState._buildAppBar.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package: myapp/presentation/newsfeed.dart:78:30)
#3      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:351:24)
#4      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:656:11)
#5      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:313:5)
#6      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:246:7)
#7      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:703:9)
#8      PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/<…>

Below is my current code version:
main.dart:
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter_platform_widgets/flutter_platform_widgets.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:myapp/presentation/newsfeed.dart';

void main() {
  // Ensure that plugin services are initialized (required by camera dep).
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

/// The route configuration.
final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
  routes: <RouteBase>[
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        return const NewsfeedPage();
      },
    ),
  ],
);


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const primaryColor = Color(0xffffee00);

  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PlatformApp.router(
      onGenerateTitle: (context) => AppLocalizations.of(context)!.appName,
      localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
      supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
      material: (context, target) => MaterialAppRouterData(
          theme: ThemeData(
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: primaryColor),
            useMaterial3: true,
          ),
          darkTheme: ThemeData(
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
                seedColor: primaryColor, brightness: Brightness.dark),
            useMaterial3: true,
          )
      ),
      cupertino: (context, target) => CupertinoAppRouterData(
        theme: const CupertinoThemeData(
          primaryColor: primaryColor,
        ),
      ),
      routerConfig: _router,
    );
  }
}

newsfeed.dart:
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter_platform_widgets/flutter_platform_widgets.dart';
import 'package:infinite_scroll_pagination/infinite_scroll_pagination.dart';
import 'package:myapp/data/models/post.dart';
import 'package:myapp/data/repositories/posts.dart';
import 'package:myapp/domain/newsfeed/bloc.dart';
import 'package:myapp/domain/newsfeed/events.dart';
import 'package:myapp/domain/newsfeed/states.dart';
import 'package:myapp/presentation/new_post.dart';
import 'package:myapp/presentation/newsfeed_card.dart';
import 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/modal_bottom_sheet.dart';

class NewsfeedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewsfeedPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _NewsfeedPageState();
}

class _NewsfeedPageState extends State<NewsfeedPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PlatformScaffold(
        appBar: _buildAppBar(context),
        body: BlocListener(
          bloc: _initBloc(),
          listener: (BuildContext context, state) {
            // React on BLoC events
          },
          child: _buildMainWidgets(context),
        ));
  }

  NewsfeedBloc _initBloc() {
    final bloc = /* Initialize BLoC */;
    return bloc;
  }

  PlatformAppBar _buildAppBar(BuildContext context) {
    final localization = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;
    return PlatformAppBar(
      title: Text(localization.newsfeedTitle),
      trailingActions: [
        PlatformIconButton(
          cupertinoIcon: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.add),
          cupertino: (context, target) => CupertinoIconButtonData(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
            onPressed: () => _onCupertinoAddPressed(context),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildMainWidgets(BuildContext context) {
    return /* Build a lot of child widgets */
  }

  void _onCupertinoAddPressed(BuildContext context) {
    CupertinoScaffold.showCupertinoModalBottomSheet(
        context: context, builder: (context) => NewPostPage());
  }
}

new_post.dart:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter_platform_widgets/flutter_platform_widgets.dart';
import 'package:myapp/domain/post_form_validator/cubit.dart';
import 'package:myapp/domain/post_form_validator/states.dart';

class NewPostPage extends StatelessWidget {

  NewPostPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocSelector<PostFormValidatorCubit, PostFormValidatorState,
        AutovalidateMode>(
      bloc: _formValidatorCubit,
      selector: (state) => state.autovalidateMode,
      builder: (context, AutovalidateMode autovalidateMode) {
        final localization = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;
        return PlatformScaffold(
          appBar: PlatformAppBar(
            title: const Text("New post"),
            trailingActions: [
              _buildActionButton(context, localization.actionPost),
            ],
          ),
          body: /* Build form fields */,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildActionButton(BuildContext context, String title) {
    /* Create an action button */
  }
}

P.S. I've tried to call showCupertinoModalBottomSheet(), it works but still not as I expect:

There is no the stack effect, just a simple bottom page.

To display the stack effect, you need to use CupertinoScaffold and the showCupertinoModalBottomSheet method within it, like this:
    class BottomSheetExample extends StatelessWidget {
      const BottomSheetExample({super.key});
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return CupertinoScaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                CupertinoScaffold.showCupertinoModalBottomSheet(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return const Text(
                      'Cupertino bottom sheet',
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
              child: const Text(
                'Show cupertino bottom sheet',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

You forgot to wrap the page in CupertinoScaffold.
